# При минификации js происходит путанница переменных

Tags: javascript, frontend, минификация

Есть код на JS:

```
success: function (data) {
     if (data.isSuccessful) {
         let result = JSON.parse(data.data);
         localStorage.setItem("MAT", result.Tokens.AccessToken);
         localStorage.setItem("MRT", result.Tokens.RefreshToken);                                                                                    
         updateTokenTime(result.Tokens.GenerationTime);
         let IV = _encoding.base64ToArray(result.IVBase64);
         _crypto.genereateAesKeyByPassPhrase(password, 128)
             .then(aesKey => {
                  userAesKey = aesKey;
                  console.log(aesKey);
                  return _crypto.decryptAes(aesKey, IV, result.EncryptedPrivateKey);
              }, error => { reject(error); })
              .then(privateKey => {
                    userPrivateKey = privateKey;
                    resolve();
              }, error => { reject(error); });                            
      } else {
         reject(data.errorMessages);
        }
      }
```

Который минифицируется в следующий:

```
if (n.isSuccessful) {
   ...
   r.genereateAesKeyByPassPhrase(t, 128).then(n=>c = n, console.log(n), ..., n=>{
        f(n)
     }
     ).then(n=>{
     ...
     }
     , n=>{
        f(n)
     }
     )
 } else
   f(n.errorMessages)
}
```

И при минификации происходит переименовывания `aesKey` в `n`, которое выше имеет имя `data` в исходном коде. Из-за чего в последствие при обращении к `aesKey` я по сути получаю `data`, что подтверждает `console.log(aesKey)`, который выводит значение переменной `data`. Как с этим бороться? Использую `BundlerMinifier`

Скрины отладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой минификатор тоже задает переменной такое же имя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте terser например, у него тонких настроек полно, и можно убрать обфускацию переменных. Вы не указали чем минифицируете. И возможно это баг, переменные должны нормально разрешаться.

Comment: Нет, то что вы описали не может быть. Попробуйте посмотреть значение переменных под дебагом.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko под дебагом все так, как я описал, скрины добавил

Comment: А у вас, случайно, нигде не перезаписывается `data` переменная? Приведите весь код, без сокращений.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko нет, нигде не перезаписывается

Comment: скорее всего не хватает фигурных скобок `.then(n=>{c = n, console.log(n), ..., }, n=>{...` или круглых

Comment: Да, попробуйте исходный код переписать `aesKey => {` на `function(aesKey){`. Скорее всего проблема в `c = n, console.log(n)` - точнее, в операторе запятая.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, вы правы, спасибо. Оформите как ответ?